# Динамически добавить обработчик к элементу в ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Доброго всем времени суток!
Правильно ли я понимаю, что в React нельзя добавить обработчик динамически через нативную функцию JS, так как теряется контекст?
Вот собственно код:

```
render(){
          return (
                  <ul>
                      {
list.map(function(item, index){
                          return <li key={index} onClick={this.showLi}>{item}</li>
                        })
                      }
                  </ul>
                )
        }
```

И можно ли как-то привязать обработчик к контексту компонента/класса?

Answer (score 0):

`Arrow function` не сохраняют контекст в отличии от стандартной анонимной функции, те замените `list.map((item, index) => <li ...` и контекст будет содержать текущий реакт компонент